# Repository or DAO: read data from multiple tables

Tags: repository, repository-pattern, dao

We have a class in which we have methods:

- find: select + multiple joins in order to filter data
- add: insert in multiple table
- update: update in multiple table
- delete: delete in multiple table
- check: multiple select + multiple joins in order to check something

Is it a Repository or a DAO?

Comment: To me there is no difference between Repository or DAO, because they do exactly same thing.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR;**
This looks more like Repository to me; personally.

---

There is a good part of controversy between Repository and DAO among purists. Many developers use terms DAO and Repository interchangeably. I personally do not put myself deep in that debate. I prefer to focus on my application needs instead.

Following is **very rough** description of some of the patterns used in Data Access Layer:

**Unit Of Work:**

- Handle database connection and transactions.
- Additionally handle cache, batch queries, tracking etc.
- Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39909985/5779732) answer.

**Repository:**

- May use UnitOfWork; not always.
- Not per table, it is per aggregate root.
- Returns Domain Object; NOT Object State (Entity/POCO).
- Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1364702/5779732) answer. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46175582/5779732) other answer for few more terms.

**DAO (Data Access Objects):**

- Tightly bound to database instead of Business Logic.
- Mostly 1:1 mapping with tables.
- Each action is transaction.
- Returns Object State (Entity/POCO).

**CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation):**

- Use a different model to write (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) data than the model you use to read (SELECT) data.
- Write operations are covered under Command.
- Read operations are covered under Query.
- Each layer can be optimized independently for specific needs.

**Query Object:**

- Accept queries as an object in parameter of method.

**Data Mapper:**

- Map POCO/Entity classes with database row and vice versa.
- ORMs (Object Relational Mappers) are based on this pattern.

**Active Record:**

- Properties and Methods related to instance are in same class.
- Mapping happens in same class.
- Acts on single record.